# Make-distribution.sh failed to build spark 2.4.3

Tags: maven, apache-spark, build, runnable-jar

I have cloned the spark project from the github and added the scoverage plugin into the parent pom.xml, and set the zincZerver to false and added a reporting tag into the pom.xml following are the changes i have made into the pom.xml.

```
<useZincServer>false</useZincServer>
```

**in properties tag**

```
 <scoverage.scalacPluginVersion>1.3.1</scoverage.scalacPluginVersion>
    <scoverage.aggregate>true</scoverage.aggregate>
```

**after the build**

```
  <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

after making the change i made the change in build command of make-distribution.sh which is:

```
BUILD_COMMAND=("$MVN" -T 1C -DskipTests clean scoverage:package $@)
```

now while running the command make-distribution.sh --pip --r --tzg and all other tags with --mvn -DskipTests clean package it gives me this output.

```
+ DISTDIR=/home/linuxuser/spark-new/spark/dist
+ MAKE_TGZ=false
+ MAKE_PIP=false
+ MAKE_R=false
+ NAME=none
+ MVN=/home/linuxuser/spark-new/spark/build/mvn
+ ((  17  ))
+ case $1 in
+ NAME=custom-scoverage-spark
+ shift
+ shift
+ ((  15  ))
+ case $1 in
+ MAKE_PIP=true
+ shift
+ ((  14  ))
+ case $1 in
+ MAKE_R=true
+ shift
+ ((  13  ))
+ case $1 in
+ MAKE_TGZ=true
+ shift
+ ((  12  ))
+ case $1 in
+ break
+ '[' -z /opt/java ']'
+ '[' -z /opt/java ']'
++ command -v git
+ '[' /usr/bin/git ']'
++ git rev-parse --short HEAD
+ GITREV=5f4b50513c
+ '[' '!' -z 5f4b50513c ']'
+ GITREVSTRING=' (git revision 5f4b50513c)'
+ unset GITREV
++ command -v /home/linuxuser/spark-new/spark/build/mvn
+

 '[' '!' /home/linuxuser/spark-new/spark/build/mvn ']'
++ /home/linuxuser/spark-new/spark/build/mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -Psparkr -Phadoop-2.7 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pmesos -Pyarn -Pkubernetes --mvn -DskipTests clean package -Dscala.version=2.12.6
++ grep -v INFO
++ grep -v WARNING
++ tail -n 1
+ VERSION=' -X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output
'
```

can someone tell me what's wrong it would be really helpful.

Thanks you

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by just executing `./make-distribution.sh` no addition tags.